# Difference in lambda expressions between full .NET framework and .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, .net-4.8

Is there a difference in the declaration of lambda expressions between the .NET Framework and .NET Core?

The following expressions compiles in .NET Core:

```
var lastShift = timeline.Appointments
                        .OfType<DriverShiftAppointment>()
                        .SelectMany(x => x.Activities.Where(x => !x.IsTheoretical))
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Start)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

But not in the .NET framework.

The problem in this expression is the following part

```
.SelectMany(x => x.Activities.Where(x => !x.IsTheoretical))
```

where `x` is declared twice (`SelectMany` and `Where`).

This is the error in the .NET Framework:

> A local or parameter named 'x' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

.NET framework

[image]

Reproducable example:

```
public class DemoClass
{
    public IList<int> Numbers { get; set; } = new List<int>();
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var lst = new List<DemoClass>
        {
            new DemoClass
            {
                Numbers = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }
            },
            new DemoClass
            {
                Numbers = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }
            },
            new DemoClass
            {
                Numbers = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }
            }
        };

        var result = lst.SelectMany(x => x.Numbers.Where(x => x % 2 == 0))
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x);

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Comment: @500-InternalServerError sorry, missed that part.

Comment: Interesting... Can you create a [mcve] we can copy/paste?

Comment: @canton7 I'll make one

Comment: @canton7 I've added a very basic and complete sample.

Comment: Interestingly, SharpLab [is fine](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgdgpgLgZgHgGiiAbhATgSxgTwQExAGoAfAAQCYBGAWACgyAGAAjKoBYBuep1qgOgAymMAEdudHhT4B2egG96zZXwBsrdswCyAQxEAKNowDaAXWY70AcwDOASiUrFdFa+YpLzOMwC8zSADuZszyzABEUBA2UGHMAL4Sbioe6MzoUQCuADZQvl78AMoQWRAAxlC6YDj63j4AfPkA6gAWGBA1vg3eDQDkAII9dnaJKnH0cUA), but dotnetfiddle [isn't](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qZrZ1T)

Comment: Why do you call .net framework "full"?

Comment: @abc667 right, will change this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is telling you that problem is this line:

```
.SelectMany(x => x.Activities.Where(x => !x.IsTheoretical))
```

Using the x twice confuses it, it is ambiguous, try this:

```
.SelectMany(x => x.Activities.Where(y => !y.IsTheoretical))
```

But you are right, it compiles in core but not framework. It looks to be like this: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/38377. Reading that link, it looks like this is a change in C# 8.0, and core is targeting 8.0 while framework is targeting 7.2.

Comment: That is totally clear and easy to solve, but not the problem. The problem is, why is it working under .net core?

Comment: Probably differences in C# compiler. Anyway try to avoid this.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv yes, it is already fixed, just seen this when using the same code in .net core and .net framework.

Comment: @BendEg yes you are correct, I missed that point. I don't know why this is.

Comment: Nice find on the issue. It would be good if you could update your answer to say that this is a change introduced in C# 8, and not a .NET Core / .NET Framework difference